# DP urlopen in gateway script for datapower

Tags: javascript, xslt-1.0, gateway, ibm-datapower

Can anybody please provide me a sample gateway script with dp-url open() contains.
1. dynamic headers
2.https call
3. response type is json
4.ssl client profile
5.form url encoded
6. POST

And how to use a specific value in response.

please help me, this is very much helpful to me,
Thanks in advance,
Manoj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample code for url open in Datapower.

var options = {
    target: endPoint url,
    method: 'post',
    timeout: 60,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": Auth
    },
    data: json
  };

```
urlOpen.open(options, function(error, response) {

  if (error) {

    session.reject("Unexpected error in readAsJSON(): " + error);

    return;
  } else {
    response.readAsJSON(function(error, jsonObj) {
      if (error) {
        session.reject("Unexpected error in readAsJSON(): " + error);
        return;
      } else {
        session.output.write(jsonObj);
      } 
    });
  }
});
```